# Can we fetch all the photos from the Google Drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am asking a general question, Can i fetch all photos from the Google Drive without Downloading process.I am using a Google Drive SDK and i am very stuck for finding the solution.Any one have experience in google drive sdk. Please share your experience.Thanks for any help.

I want only fetch the Google Drive Photos not download in our application.

Comment: Not sure but I think you can use this library https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/code
Try once

Comment: ok thank you, i am going to try...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Drive's [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) while using the code snippet on the [Querying for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/queries) section of the documentation

I checked the [Supported MIME Type](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) section, and you can set the `q` attribute as

```
NSString *search = @"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.photo'";
GTLServiceDrive *drive = ...;
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = search;
[drive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
GTLDriveFileList *fileList,
NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Have results");
        // Iterate over fileList.files array
    } else {
        NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
    }
}];
```